# Trying to set up an Autocomplete Preference field

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a developed a little up to let me know if my computer is online over the Internet and it works fine. The thing is, I noticed that my preferences input boxes dont have the keyboard suggestions enabled. Suggestions do work on the emulator but not on my galaxy s7 edge.

here is the XML code for the preferences activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/settingsHeader">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="ip"
            android:title="@string/ip"
            android:summary="@string/ipsummary"
            android:defaultValue="192.168.1.1"
            android:id="@+id/ip"/>
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="port"
            android:title="@string/port"
            android:summary="@string/portsummary"
            android:defaultValue="23"
            android:id="@+id/port"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and here is the java file of the activity:

```
public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "SettingsAcitivity";
    private EditText ip;
    private EditText port;
    public static Context context;

    public MyPreferenceActivity() {

        context = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

       ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
       port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
     //  ip.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
       //port.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {


        private final static String TAG = "MyPreferenceFragment";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_preference);

            findPreference("ip").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                    new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,toastMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.ipUpdated), newValue),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
            findPreference("port").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                    new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,toastMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.portUpdated), newValue),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    public static String toastMessage(String updated, Object newValue){
        return updated + " " + newValue.toString();
    }
}
```

I have many apps where the preferences do have keyboard suggestions so I suppose its doable somehow.